# IntelliJ IDEA doesn't intercept JLine code completion in bebug mode

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, autocomplete, jline

I tried to run simple Java application wich is used code completion. When I run it in separate console it works like a charm. But when I try to it via IntelliJ IDEA, then my IDE doesn't intercept code completion actions in debug mode.

I tried to add to my VM options

```
-Djline.terminal=jline.UnsupportedTerminal
```

But it doesn't help me.

Maybe there is someone who faced with this problem?

Comment: Jline code completion is not compatible with Idea's console (see [the discussion about this bug](https://github.com/jline/jline2/issues/185) and `jline.WindowsTerminal` class javadoc)

Answer (score 0):

```
 jline.TerminalFactory.registerFlavor(TerminalFactory.Flavor.WINDOWS, jline.UnsupportedTerminal.class);
```

Comment: The description of your solution would help to understand it.

Comment: As I understand, it's the same as adding of `-Djline.terminal=jline.UnsupportedTerminal` into parameters