# JLine Java program is not interactive via IntelJ console

Tags: interactive, jcommander

I want to run a Java program via IntelJ, this program use Jcommander which enable it to get commands from the console and process it, the problem is that currently the console is not interactive meaning it opens the prompt but doesn't except any input, i know that there is some VM argument that should be added to the IntelJ run configuration in order to have the console interactive, does anyone know which VM argument it is? Or any other suggestion on how to have the console interactive?

the code is stuck on this line:

```
while ((line = consoleReader.readLine("cp> ")) != null )
```

the console looks like this:

```
2016-10-11 10:47:19 [main] INFO  Cli:197 - Starting CLI

cp>
```

When I run it via executable jar it works fine and the user can interact with the program.

- correction: the program uses Jcommander but the actual consoleReader is of JLine

Comment: Most probably the "console" that IntelliJ simulates doesn't support the consoleReader that JCommander uses

Comment: I found the solution to my problem here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28571678/intellij-idea-doesnt-intercept-jline-code-completion-in-bebug-mode  adding this VM argument solved the issue -Djline.terminal=jline.UnsupportedTerminal